# Mongoose $or operator not working properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i am trying to perform a simple query just to check if we have that record.

```
const exists = await Book.findOne({ $or: [{ author_id: item.id }, { author_id: item.network.code }] });
```

The problem that a non existing record when checking still gets found and returns something like where author_id is not even present. Sometimes one of the values `item.id` or `item.network.code` can be null or undefined but i need it to match the exact thing if its available. What am i missing here?

Collection example

```
_id:60a308208b70ad7e14f41cc9
author_id: s76yrb0g78ers87ngyre0s78yeyrst08n7y
title: 'Lord of the rings'
created_at: 2021-05-18T00:19:44.058+00:00
__v:0
```

What it actually returns

```
_id:70b308307b60ad7e14f51cd9
title: 'Harry Potter'
created_at: 2021-07-18T00:20:12.040+00:00
__v:0
```

Comment: Please add an input collection example

Comment: @J.F. added example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a long and tedious way to check but i basically done the following and it worked fine

```
let exists = false;

if (item.network?.code) {
  exists = await Book.findOne({ author_id: item.network.code });
}

if (item.id && !exists) {
  exists = await Book.findOne({ author_id: item.id });
}
```

If there's any cleaner way to do this please let me know.